# Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined at generatePDF

Tags: php, html, html-table, jspdf

Dear All I'm facing a problem with this code which is basically my page tables from Database and I want to download this page as a PDF format but I can not I don't know what the issue I spent days solving this and nothing changed, I try the DOMPDF but its output ??? my code pretty long but most of it table display from the database, I will appreciate you help.

```
<?php
 require('db2.php');
// require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
// use Dompdf\Dompdf; 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.10.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script> 
<!-- <script src="scriptPDF.js"></script> -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
 crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<title> Invoice Details </title>
<link  rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css">

<style>
    body{
        background-color: white;
    }

.header-company{
text-align: right ;
height: 20px;
color: black;
text-align: justify;
text-justify: inter-word;
}

header img{
    position: relative;
    align-items : center;
    top: 1%;
    left: 9%;
    right: 20%;
}

.billTo-css{
 
    display: inline;

}
.billTo-css #billE{
    float:left;
    bottom: 30px;
}

.billTo-css #billAR{

    float:right;
    
    
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<!-- //  $dompdf = new Dompdf();
//  $html = file_get_contents('InvoiceDetails.php'); 
//  $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
//  $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
//  $dompdf->render();

// //output the generated PDF
// ob_end_clean();
// $dompdf->stream("",array("Attachment" => false));
//  exit(0);  -->


<?php


if(isset($_GET ['SearchByInvoiceID']))
    {
        $id= $_GET ['SearchByInvoiceID'];

    $stmt= "Select top 1* from [Portal].[fn_GetInvoicesBySerial]($id)";
    $query_run = sqlsrv_query($conn,$stmt);
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query_run ))
    
{
    

?>  

 <form method="get" action="InvoiceDetails.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">
 
  <header> 
  <center>
   <!-- <div class="header-QR"> -->
   

   <h2> TAX Invoice </h2> </center>
   <center> <img src=<?php echo $row ['QRLink']; ?> </center>    
    

<div class="header-company">
<h3 align="right"> <?php echo $row ['CompanyNameA'];?> </h3>
<h3 align="right"> <?php echo $row ['CompanyNameE']; ?>  </h3>
<p align="right"> CR No: <?php echo $row ['CRNo']; ?>  </p>
<p align="right"> VAT ID:<?php echo $row ['VATID']; ?>  </p>
<p align="right"> Group VAT ID <?php echo $row ['GroupVATID']; ?>  </p>
<p align="right"> Tel: <?php echo $row ['Tel']; ?>  </p>
<p align="right"> Email: <?php echo $row ['email']; ?>  </p> 
</form>
<br>

<br>
    </div>
    </header>
     
    <br> 
     
    <?php  
    if( $query_run === false ) {
        print( print_r( sqlsrv_errors() ) );
    }

    ?>
    
   <?php


    }


}

    ?>
    
    
    <!-- <div class="table-css"> -->
<!-- <tr>
    <th> Department </th>
    <th>Type </th>      
    <th>Branch </th>   
    <th> Branch CR No</th>   
    <th>Salesman </th>   
    <th> Account# </th>   
    <th> Application ID </th>   
    <th>Invoicen Timestamp </th>   
    <th>Issued By </th>   
    <th>Print By </th>   
</tr> -->

<?php

if(isset($_GET ['SearchByInvoiceID']))
    {
        $id= $_GET ['SearchByInvoiceID'];

    
    
    $stmt= "Select top 1* from [Portal].[fn_GetInvoicesBySerial]($id)";
    $query_run = sqlsrv_query($conn,$stmt);
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query_run )) {
    

        ?>
        <br>
        <br>
<div class="row">
   <div class="column">
   <table>
<tr>
    
     <tr> 
         <th> Department </th>
   <td> <?php echo $row ['DepartmentCode']; ?> <th>  القسم  </th> </td> </tr>
     
   <tr>
      <th>Type </th> 
   <td> <?php echo $row ['InvoiceType']; ?>  </td> <th>  النوع  </th> </tr>
   
   <tr>
      <th>Branch </th>
   <td> <?php echo $row ['Branch']; ?>  </td> <th>  الفرع  </th> </tr>
   
   <tr>
   <th> Branch CR No</th>  
   <td> <?php echo $row ['BranchCRNo']; ?>  </td> <th>  س ت للفرع  </th> </tr>
   
   <tr>
   <th>Salesman </th> 
   <td> <?php echo $row ['Salesman']; ?>  </td> <th>  أسم البائع  </th> </tr>
    
</tr>
    </table>
    </div>
   
    <div class="column">
    <table>
   <tr>
   <tr>
   <th> Account # </th>   
   <td> <?php echo $row ['AccountNo']; ?>  </td> <th>  #فاتورة   </th> </tr>
   
   <tr>
   <th> Application ID </th>   
   <td> <?php echo $row ['ApplicationID']; ?>  </td> <th> # مرجع  </th> </tr>
   
   <tr>
   <th>Invoicen Timestamp </th>   
   <td> <?php echo $row ['InvoiceTimeStamp']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?> </td> <th>  طلب الشراء  </th></tr>
   
   <tr>
   <th>Issued By </th>   
   <td> <?php echo $row ['Issuedby']; ?>  </td><th>  تاريخ الأستحقاق  </th> </tr>
   
   <tr>
   <th>Print By </th> 
   <td> <?php echo $row ['Printedby']; ?>  </td> <th>  رقم سند القبض  </th></tr>

</tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>

<?php  
    if( $query_run === false ) {
        print( print_r( sqlsrv_errors() ) );
    }
    ?>
    
   <?php

}
    }

    ?>
    <br>
<!-- <div class="table-css">
<h3> Bill To </h3>
<hr>
<table>
<tr>
        <th>Customer ID </th>
        <th> Customer Name:</th>
        <th>Address: </th>
        <th>Email </th>
        <th>VAT ID: </th>
        <th>VAT Group ID </th>
        <th>Contact </th>
</tr>
</div> -->

<?php

if(isset($_GET ['SearchByInvoiceID']))
    {
        $id= $_GET ['SearchByInvoiceID'];

    
    
    $stmt= "Select top 1* from [Portal].[fn_GetInvoicesBySerial]($id)";
    $query_run = sqlsrv_query($conn,$stmt);
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query_run )) {
    
        ?>
        <!-- <div class="billTo-css">
            <div id="billE">
        <h3> Bill To </h3> </div> <br>
        <div id="billAR">
        <h3> صادرة الى </h3> </div> 
    <br>
    </div>  -->
        <br> 
        <div class="row">
   <div class="column">
  
    <table>
   <h3> Bill to </h3>
<tr>
<tr>
<th>Customer ID </th>
<td> <?php echo $row ['CustomerID']; ?>  </td> <th>  رقم العميل  </th> </tr>
<tr>
<th> Customer Name:</th> 
<td> <?php echo $row ['CustomerName']; ?>  </td> <th>  اسم العميل  </th> </tr>
<tr>
<th>Address: </th>  
<td> <?php echo $row ['CustomerAddress']; ?>  </td> <th>  العنوان  </th></tr>
<tr>
<th>Email </th>
<td> <?php echo $row ['CustomerEmail']; ?>  </td><th>  بريد الكتروني  </th> </tr>

</table>
    </div>
   
    <div class="column">

<table>
 <h3> صادرة الى  </h3>
<tr>
<tr>
<th>VAT ID: </th>
<td> <?php echo $row ['CustomerVATID']; ?>  </td> <th>  رقم الضريبي  </th> </tr>
<tr>
<th>VAT Group ID </th>
<td> <?php echo $row ['CustomerVATGroupID']; ?>  </td> <th>  رقم ضريبي عام  </th> </tr>

<tr>
<th>ID/CR No</th>
<td> <?php echo $row ['CRNo']; ?>  </td> <th> هوية/سجل تجاري  </th> </tr>

<tr>
<th>Contact </th>  
<td> <?php echo $row ['CustomerTel']; ?>  </td> <th> هاتف تواصل  </th> </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
    </div>
    </div>
<hr size ="1">

    <?php  
    if( $query_run === false ) {
        print( print_r( sqlsrv_errors() ) );
    }
    ?>
    
   <?php

}
    }

    ?>
    <hr size ="1">
    <div class="table-css">
    <hr>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    
<th>Line Description <br>
     وصف الصنف               </th> 
<th>Qunatity  <br>
    عدد          </th> 
<th> Unit Price <br>
    سعر الوحدة      </th> 
<th>SubTotal <br>
    الإجمالي     </th> 
<th>Discount <br>
      خصم      </th>
<th>Net  <br>
بعد الخصم   </th> 
<th>VAT Rate  <br>
    ضريبة      </th> 
<th>VAT Amount  <br>
    ضريبة      </th>
<th>Total Plus VAT <br>
الضريبة+الصافي </th>
</tr>
</div>
<br>
<?php

    if(isset($_GET ['SearchByInvoiceID']))
    {
     $id= $_GET ['SearchByInvoiceID'];
     $stmt= " select top 1 * from [Portal].[fn_GetInvoicesDetails] ($id)";
    $query_run = sqlsrv_query($conn,$stmt);
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query_run)) {
    
    
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $row ['LineDescription']; ?> </td> 
        <td> <?php echo $row ['Qunatity']; ?> </td> 
        <td> <?php echo $row ['UnitPrice']; ?> </td> 
        <td> <?php echo $row ['SubTotal']; ?> </td> 
        <td> <?php echo $row ['Discount']; ?> </td> 
        <td> <?php echo $row ['Net']; ?> </td> 
        <td> <?php echo $row ['VATRate']; ?> </td> 
        <td> <?php echo $row ['VATAmount']; ?> </td> 
        <td> <?php echo $row ['TotalPlusVAT']; ?> </td> 
    </tr>
    
        <?php  
    if( $query_run === false ) {
        print( print_r( sqlsrv_errors() ) );
    }
    ?>
    
   <?php

}
    }

?>
</table>
<br>
<!-- <div class="table-css">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> VAT Summary</th>
        <th>SR </th>
        <th>Totals </th>
        <th>SR</th>
    </tr>
</div> -->
    <?php

if(isset($_GET ['SearchByInvoiceID']))
    {
        $id= $_GET ['SearchByInvoiceID'];

    
    
    $stmt= "Select top 1* from [Portal].[fn_GetInvoicesBySerial]($id)";
    $query_run = sqlsrv_query($conn,$stmt);
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query_run )) {
   
        ?>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="column">
  
  <table>
<tr>
<tr>
 <h3> VAT Summary </h3>
 <h3> ملخص ضريبي </h3>
<th> Taxable Amount BeforeVAT</th>
<td> <?php echo $row ['TaxableAmountBeforeVAT']; ?>  </td>  <th>  القيمة الخاضعة للضريبة </th> </tr>
<tr>
<th>VAT </th>  
<td> <?php echo $row ['TotalVAT']; ?>  </td>  <th>  ضريبة  </th> </tr>
<tr>
<th>Taxable Amount Plus VAT </th>  
<td>  <?php echo $row ['TaxableAmountPlusVAT']; ?>  </td>  <th>  القيمة الخاضعة+الضريبة  </th> </tr>

<tr>
<th>Non Taxable Amount </th>
<td> <?php echo $row ['NonTaxableAmount']; ?>  </td>  <th> قيمة غير خاضعة للضريبة  </th> </tr>
<tr>
<th> 
<br> <br> </th>
<td>   </td> </tr>
</tr>

</table>
    </div>
   
<div class="column">

<table>
<tr>
<tr>
     <h3> Totals </h3>
     <h3> الأجماليات </h3>
<th>Sub Total Before Discount </th>  
<td> <?php echo $row ['SubTotalBeforeDiscount']; ?>  </td>  <th>  الأجمالي </th> </tr>
<tr>
<th> Total Discount</th>
<td> <?php echo $row ['TotalDiscount']; ?>  </td>  <th>  الخصم  </th> </tr>
<tr>
<th>Total After Discount </th>
<td> <?php echo $row ['SubTotalAfterDiscount']; ?> </td>  <th>  بعد الخصم </th> </tr>
<tr>
<th>VAT </th>
<td> <?php echo $row ['TotalVAT']; ?>  </td>  <th> ضريبة </th> </tr>
<tr>
<th>Total Plus VAT </th>
<td> <?php echo $row ['TotalPlusVAT']; ?>  </td>  <th>  الصافي+الضريبة </th> </tr>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php  
    if( $query_run === false ) {
        print( print_r( sqlsrv_errors() ) );
    }
    ?>
    
   <?php

}
    }

?>
</table>

<!-- Additional Notes part-->

<?php

if(isset($_GET ['SearchByInvoiceID']))
    {
        $id= $_GET ['SearchByInvoiceID'];

        
    
    $stmt= "Select top 1* from [Portal].[fn_GetInvoicesBySerial]($id)";
    $query_run = sqlsrv_query($conn,$stmt);
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query_run )) {
    

        ?>
    <h2> ملاحظات اضافية</h2>
    <h2> Additional Notes </h2>
    <?php echo $row ['AdditionalNotes']; ?> 
    <?php  
    if( $query_run === false ) {
        print( print_r( sqlsrv_errors() ) );
    }
    ?>
    
   <?php

}
    }

?>
<div id="InvoiceDetails-PDF">
    <td align="center">
   
    <a href="javascript:generatePDF()">Dowload PDF</a>
    </td>
 </div>
   <script>

function generatePDF() {
 var doc = new jsPDF();  //create jsPDF object
  doc.fromHTML(document.getElementById("InvoiceDetails-PDF"), // page element which you want to print as PDF
  15,
  15, 
  {
    'width': 170  //set width
  },
  function(a) 
   {
    doc.save("HTML2PDF.pdf"); // save file name as HTML2PDF.pdf
  });
}

   </script> 

  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"but its output ???"_ - Where? How? When? Please add a more detailed explanation of your issue. You should also read [how to create a _**minimal**_, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of dumping all the code. Often when you get ?, it's due på encoding issues, but I don't know enough about your issue to know if that's the case here. Anyway, have a look at [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) and see if that helps.

Comment: the ??? mark output when I use the DOMPDF library, I try to use it but it outputs something wrong so I try to use another l library which is html2pdf.s